# Eclipse Neon contantly freezing

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

Eclipse Neon is freezing constantly, no more than two minutes after being started. There are no error messages or exceptions shown, the workbench simply stops responding. In the .log file are innumerate exceptions like:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2016-08-15 20:13:31.283
!MESSAGE Unable to create part
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-08-15 20:13:31.284
!MESSAGE 
!SESSION 2016-08-15 20:13:47.804 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_101
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-08-15 20:14:04.086
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.swt.SWTException: Failed to execute runnable (org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Browser style SWT.MOZILLA and Java system property org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla are not supported with GTK 3 as XULRunner is not ported for GTK 3 yet])
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4533)
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4448)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runAsyncMessages(Display.java:4528)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4146)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: org.eclipse.swt.SWTError: No more handles [Browser style SWT.MOZILLA and Java system property org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla are not supported with GTK 3 as XULRunner is not ported for GTK 3 yet]
    at org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(SWT.java:4559)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.MozillaDelegate.<init>(MozillaDelegate.java:57)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Mozilla.create(Mozilla.java:667)
    at org.eclipse.swt.browser.Browser.<init>(Browser.java:99)
    at de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.PageBookBrowserPage.createBrowser(PageBookBrowserPage.java:254)
    at de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.PageBookBrowserPage.createControl(PageBookBrowserPage.java:242)
    at de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.ManagedPageBookView.doCreatePage(ManagedPageBookView.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.createPage(PageBookView.java:400)
    at org.eclipse.ui.part.PageBookView.partActivated(PageBookView.java:743)
    at de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.ManagedPageBookView.newPage(ManagedPageBookView.java:509)
    at de.walware.statet.r.internal.ui.rhelp.RHelpView$1$1.run(RHelpView.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.RunnableLock.run(RunnableLock.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Synchronizer.runAsyncMessages(Synchronizer.java:182)
    ... 24 more

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 0 2016-08-15 20:14:37.047
!MESSAGE Unhandled event loop exception
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invokeUsingClass(InjectorImpl.java:282)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.InjectorImpl.invoke(InjectorImpl.java:264)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory.invoke(ContextInjectionFactory.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceHandler.execute(HandlerServiceHandler.java:152)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.Command.executeWithChecks(Command.java:494)
    at org.eclipse.core.commands.ParameterizedCommand.executeWithChecks(ParameterizedCommand.java:488)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.commands.internal.HandlerServiceImpl.executeHandler(HandlerServiceImpl.java:210)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.executeCommand(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:286)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.press(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:507)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.processKeyEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.filterKeySequenceBindings(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:378)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher.access$0(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:324)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.bindings.keys.KeyBindingDispatcher$KeyDownFilter.handleEvent(KeyBindingDispatcher.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.filterEvent(Display.java:1605)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1339)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1366)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1349)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendKeyEvent(Widget.java:1378)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.gtk_key_press_event(Widget.java:764)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.gtk_key_press_event(Control.java:3457)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.gtk_key_press_event(Composite.java:801)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.windowProc(Widget.java:2000)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.windowProc(Control.java:5819)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.windowProc(Display.java:5490)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._gtk_main_do_event(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.gtk_main_do_event(OS.java:9545)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.eventProc(Display.java:1275)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS._g_main_context_iteration(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.swt.internal.gtk.OS.g_main_context_iteration(OS.java:2495)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:4141)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$4.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1121)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1022)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:604)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:134)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:388)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:243)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1519)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1492)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.PageBookBrowserPage.setFocusToBrowser(PageBookBrowserPage.java:376)
    at de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.PageBookBrowserPage.setDefaultFocus(PageBookBrowserPage.java:368)
    at de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.PageBookBrowserPage$1.setFocus(PageBookBrowserPage.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt.ContributedPartRenderer$2.setFocus(ContributedPartRenderer.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.CTabFolder.setFocus(CTabFolder.java:2614)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite.setFocus(Composite.java:1513)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.fixFocus(Control.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.setEnabled(Control.java:4567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.disableControl(WorkbenchWindow.java:2113)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchWindow.run(WorkbenchWindow.java:2160)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:293)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.runProgressMonitorOperation(SaveableHelper.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.saveModels(SaveableHelper.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.SaveableHelper.savePart(SaveableHelper.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveSaveable(WorkbenchPage.java:3904)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.saveEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:3918)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.SaveHandler.execute(SaveHandler.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:54)
    ... 53 more
```

Issues have been reported regarding GTK3, but even forcing GTK2 the workbench keeps on freezing. These are the contents of the `eclipse.ini` file:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.200.v20160318-1642.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
--launcher.GTK_version
2
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseStringDeduplication
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.8
-Xms256m
-Xmx1024m
```

What is causing this behaviour? Can it be fixed somehow? Note that I have no such issues with either Eclipse Mars or Eclipse Luna.

Comment: What is `de.walware.ecommons.ui.mpbv.PageBookBrowserPage`? It is not standard Eclipse and that is the class that is getting the NPE.

Comment: I am not sure, but WalWare provides the [StatET plugin](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet).

Comment: Get in tou h with the author of the de.walware part. This editor parts are tricky. Maybe installing the libwebkit-gtk3 package can help. However if walware forces usage of Mozilla browser on GTK3, you're kind of stuck inless walware author can suggest a workaround.

Comment: I'm experiencing similar instability with the latest Windows 10, running Eclipse Neon 4.6.2, Java8u66.  With Neon, I've had to kill eclipse.exe using Task Manager much more frequently (seems like once per week).  The entropy in Eclipse seems to be increasing.  I've been using Eclipse since for almost 15 years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These freezing issues went away once I removed the [StatET plug-in](http://www.walware.de/goto/statet). I opened up a discussion at the StatET mail-list that went nowhere (unfortunately, there is no active archive I could point to at the moment).

In essence: this plug-in is not stable and should be avoided.